# SQL select query to order results based on the maximum value of an associated table

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have a **customers** table and an **orders** table.

Customers table has fields: `id, name, status_id`

Orders table has fields: `id, customer_id, order_date`

Each customer can have **many** orders.

I would like to know if there is an sql query which can `select` all the `customers` `order by` status_id and the last order_date of their orders.

So, the results would list first all the customers with **status** 1, and within those it would list them from the one whose most recent order is most recent to the one whose most recent order is least recent. Then it would list those with status 2 the same way and then status 3 the same way.  In the whole list each customer should only appear once.

Eg.

customers table

```
id, name, status_id

1, john, 2  
2, jane, 1  
3, tim, 1
```

orders table

```
id, customer_id, date

1, 1, 2013-01-01  
2, 1, 2011-10-01  
3, 2, 2012-12-01  
4, 2, 2010-03-10  
5, 3, 2011-02-21  
6, 3, 2012-01-11
```

The query should give a list of customers like this

```
2 jane  
3 tim  
1 john
```

Tim and Jane are before john, because they have a status of 1. Jane is before Tim because her last order (2012-12-01) was more recent than Tim's (2012-01-11).

I tried this

```
SELECT customers.id, customers.name, customers.status_id
FROM customers
JOIN orders ON customers.id = orders.customer_id 
ORDER BY customers.status_id, orders.date
```

But some customers appear many times.

Thanks very much for your help,
Phil

Comment: Yes it's possible (most things are), but I don't see any attempt...

Comment: Thanks Mitch. Do you mind sharing an example of a query which would do this? Thank you.

Comment: maybe you should show an attempt. People will be more likely to help you, if you show some effort.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below `Query`

```
select cus.id as ID, cus.name as Name
from
customer cus
inner join order1 ord on cus.id=ord.customer_id
group by cus.id, cus.name,cus.status_id 
order by cus.status_id asc,max(ord.date)desc
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8402b/7)**

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
SELECT custome.id, customer.name FROM customer JOIN 
    `order` ON customer.id = `order`.customer_id GROUP BY customer.id ORDER BY customer.status, `order`.date DESC
```

Comment: it may not give result butit can get him started, it better to suggest some thing instead of just commenting on others answer, if you feel it's not the right answer please not what is the problem in this query.

Comment: Thanks Dharmesh Patel, This is something like what I tried. It gets the order right but some customers appear many times. I guess I maybe need a GROUP BY somewhere. Each customer should appear exactly once.

Comment: Yes you need to group them, sorry for not putting it I will edit my post, Thanks